# osm2pgrouting creates erroneous roads

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, osm2pgrouting

osm2pgrouting works without giving any errors but most of the roads have lost their geometry.

Result is ;

[image]

**What I've done so far;**

1. OSM Data downloaded from http://download.geofabrik.de/ in pbf format.
2. Data clipped and converted to osm format using the command below

`osmconvert turkey-latest.pbf -B=ankara.poly -o=ankara.osm`

3. Data is inserted into PostgreSQL using the command below;

   `osm2pgrouting --f ankara.osm --conf mapconfig.xml --dbname=workshop --host=localhost -p 5432 --username postgres -W 1 --clean`

Comment: How did you create the image above? Which SQL statement did you use?

Comment: Hi, I've taken the screen shot from QGIS, I've added PostgreSQL table as layer.

Comment: Which table specifically? Postgres is the name of your database and won't tell us what table contents you're showing here.

Comment: Not the OP, but I've been seeing this in both the (prefix-)ways table and the osm_ways table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `--complete-ways` to your `osmconvert` command.

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert#Keeping_Cross-Border_Ways_Complete

It seems that these errors can appear when osm2pgrouting encounters missing or incorrectly ordered data. Adding `--complete-ways` keeps features that cross the boundary intact.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try "osm2pgsql" instead of "osm2pgrouting".